# Webpack Error: configuration.module

Tags: javascript, webpack, configuration

I have an uncommon webpack error and I don't know how to fix it..

It has something to do with my **configuration**, but I don't know what it is. A schoolmate of mine can perfectly run `webpack` in the console with the **same project**.

Earlier I got the error:

```
PS E:\HTL\Projects\EasyWater\Software\Beispielprojekte\WebPack_Dummy> webpack
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D
```

then I installed the Webpack CLI globally and now finally I get the error:

```
PS E:\HTL\Projects\EasyWater\Software\Beispielprojekte\WebPack_Dummy> webpack
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unk
nownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
```

I have already reinstalled node js and **literally** everything, but I am continously get the same error.

As I said, my schoolmate can execute `webpack` with the **same** project.

I have installed:

- ts-loader -g
- webpack -g
- webpack-cli -g
- typescript -g

Comment: Did you even read what error states? What versions of webpack do you both have?

Comment: for webpack 4.1.0 and for webpack-cli 2.0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your friend is not using webpack 4 and you are using a `webpack.config.js` configuration file incompatible with webpack 4. I myself am walking through a tutorial involving webpack and encountered the same error. By uninstalling webpack 4 in favor of webpack 3 (`npm install webpack@3 --save-dev`), I was able to run my npm build script of `webpack --config webpack.config.js` without issue and without the need for webpack-cli. An update to the configuration file may be more appropriate, but I am just starting out with webpack and this is the path of least resistance.

Comment: My schoolmate have Version 3 of Webpack, I installed Webpack Version 3 and now I don't have to install the CLI anymore, but I still get the same error, which I mentioned above.

Comment: I use the same versions for everything, which my schoolmate has, now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using Webpack v4, change the 'loaders' option into 'rules' e.g

```
    module.exports = {
        entry: './your-entry-file',
        output: {
            ...                
          },
        module:{
           **rules**: [{ 
                  //rules replaces loaders
                  //all your configuration comes here
               }]
         }
    }
```